# C: Read from pipe char AND int, simultaneously (tricky one)

Tags: c, char, int, pipe

I am writing in a pipe some integers and when I am ending I write "11". Then, when I am reading from the same pipe, I have to take the integers and do stuff with them and when I get the "11", I should terminate. But I cannon think of any solutions to read simultaneously in the pipe for int and char (I know that is working based on a fifo method).

Any ideas?

```
//THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CODE OF WHAT I WANT TO DO 

//I am writing to the pipe
while(CONDITION)
    write(mypipe, &random_int, sizeof(short));
write(mypipe, "1", sizeof("11"));

/* code... */

//I am reading from the pipe
while(TRUE){
    read(mypipe, &received_int, sizeof(short));
    // if strcmp(receiver_int, "11")==0 then exit;
    // else do stuff with receiver_int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is just a byte stream, even if you interpreted the read bytes correctly as a 16bit integer and as a 2 character string "11" which in ASCII is the bytes `31 31`, then how do you tell "11" apart from the integer 12593? They have the same binary representation.

One option is to just keep reading until the pipe is terminated, this may be suitable say for transferring a file. But does not allow on-going back and forth messages.

```
write(mypipe, &random_int, sizeof(short));
close(mypipe); // finished writing

// recv
while (true)
{
    short received_int;
    if (read(mypipe, &received_int, sizeof(short)) == sizeof(short)) // Not handling the int getting split into two separate read's here
    {
        // Use received_int
    }
    else return; // 0 on close
}
```

This is why most protocols introduce the concept of messages on top of the stream (either in text or binary). For example you might have an 8bit "opcode" and say that 0 is "disconnect" and 1 is "message with integer", so to write an integer:

```
 unsigned char opcode = 1;
 short random_int = 55; // Make sure it actually a short, as you used sizeof(short)!
 write(mypipe, &opcode, 1);
 write(mypipe, &random_int, sizeof(short));
```

And to read you read the opcode first and then decide:

```
char opcode;
read(mypipe, &opcode, 1); // CHECK RETURN!
switch (opcode)
{
case 0: return; // Finished
case 1:
    {
        short received_int;
        read(mypipe, &received_int, sizeof(short)); // CHECK RETURN!
        // Use received_int
        break;
    }
}
```

You might look at some existing protocols on how they encode different things into the byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannon [sic] think of any solutions to read simultaneously in the pipe for int and char

There aren't any solutions to that problem *per se*, because one reads neither characters nor integers from a pipe, but rather raw bytes.  Everything else is about how the bytes are *interpreted*.

> (I know that is working based on a fifo method).

FIFOs have exactly the same constraints as pipes.

Generally speaking, if you want to pass objects of different types across *any* communications medium, you need some kind of format or protocol that enables the receiver to interpret the data as the sender intended.  That can range from very simple to very complex.  What you describe is an especially simple protocol (*too* simple, really): the data consist of byte pairs, with each pair interpreted as the bytes of an unsigned integer, except that there is a special two-byte sequence that marks the end of the data.

For such a protocol, I might write the receiving side something like this:

```
union {
    uint16_t num;
    char s[3];    // Three bytes, not two, to allow for a terminator
} buffer = { .s = { 0 }};

while (1){
    read(mypipe, &buffer, sizeof(uint16_t));
    if (strcmp(buffer.s, "11") == 0) {
        break;
    }
    // do stuff with buffer.num ...
}
```

But no, the protocol as you describe it does not provide a way to distinguish the two bytes of `"11"` from the same two bytes used as an integer value.  As a result, there is one integer value that cannot be sent via this protocol. Quite possibly it is 12593 (decimal), which would result from encoding the characters of `"11"` in ASCII and then reinterpreting the result as a two-byte integer.

Comment: thanks! how do you found 12593? I cannot find any online converter from decimal to ascii

Comment: @NickSt, there are numerous ASCII tables available all over the web.  Google will find you a dozen.  They will all tell you that the ASCII code for the decimal digit '1' is 49 (decimal).  The two byte sequence of `"11"` is therefore 49, 49 (decimal).  To convert that to a single 16-bit integer, multiply the more-significant 49 by the base (256) and add the less significant.  That is 256 * 49 + 49 = 257 * 49 = 12593.

Comment: But note well that that assumes the ASCII encoding of '1'.  Although it's encoded the same way also by UTF-8, all ISO-8859 variants, and other encodings, that encoding is not *universal*.  That's why I perform a string comparison in my example code, not a numeric one.